# Is it good practice to type-check argument in Racket

Tags: types, scheme, racket

I'm new in racket and I need as homework to write some program. Is it good practice to check the type of the arguments? For example, what is better:

```
(define (add x y)
  (+ x y)
)
```

Or

```
(define (add x y)
  (unless (number? x)(raise exception))
  (unless (number? y)(raise exception))
  (+ x y)
)
```

I can think about: type checking makes exception to be thrown earlier, and to be easier to locate. But it makes the code more complicated and less readable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Professional Racket code tends to use [contracts](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/contracts.html) for this purpose, usually on the exports of modules. The contracts both serve as documentation and also guarantee that your functions are called on correct inputs and produce correct outputs.

They also will "blame" the code that violated the terms of the contract.

For your example, you might write a contract like the following in your module:

```
(provide (contract-out [add (-> number? number? number?)]))
```

Then when other modules try to use the `add` function incorrectly, they will be blamed. Writing contracts separately like this is good practice since it separates the implementation and the specification of your code.

---

That said, unless you are taking a software engineering course and writing large programs, this is probably just a distraction. So for your assignment, don't bother.

Answer (score 2):

If you're writing a reusable module which is going to be used by other people, it makes sense to check the parameters and ensure that the types are correct, but only if the check isn't already being performed - in your example it isn't necessary to verify if the parameters are numbers, if they weren't an error would occur because of a contract violation, in other words: the type checking is already there, in the addition procedure.

Scheme uses dynamically typed variables and under normal conditions your code should not perform such checks, just take care of writing the logic of the program and worry about type-checking later (if ever).

Answer (score 1):

The addition procedure already does type-checking.  A more important question is how do you want to handle an exception.  Spend some time investigating `with-exception-handler`.